# Does qx.ui.container.Resizer send events?

Tags: events, resize, qooxdoo

Is it possible to get some events with current size during resizing of the `qx.ui.container.Resizer`?

The `resize` event is not fired nor `changeWidth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem:
To get resize events during resizing process one firstly need to get resizing frame widget: qx.ui.container.Resizer _getResizeFrame() (this is protected function so writing own class which inherits from Resizer may be needed). Then adding listener for resize event will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works fine in the playground.

```
var resizer = new qx.ui.container.Resizer().set({
    width: 200,
    height: 100
  });

  resizer.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.Canvas());
  var text = new qx.ui.form.TextArea("Resize me\nI'm resizable");
  resizer.add(text, {edge: 0});

  this.getRoot().add(resizer);

  resizer.addListener('resize',function(e){
    this.debug(resizer.getWidth());
  },this);
```

You can try the demo in the [qooxdoo playground](http://tinyurl.com/ncx77kk)

Comment: Resizer listener is called only after finishing the resize process. It is not called during resize.